# Will a wire frame trekking backpack get past security in the US and EU?

Tags: airport-security, eu, hand-luggage, tsa, prohibited-items

My Gregory backpack contains a 55 cm wire frame, which can be removed (see photo). I would like to take it as carry-on.

Could getting past security be a problem in the US or Europe?

[image: wire frame]

Comment: Does the bag fit within the size limits with the frame fitted?  You say the frame is 55cm which is already too big for some airlines and on the limit for others.  With some you'd get away with it but others measure, and it won't compress

Comment: The limit is 55cm. When inside the backpack, it makes the backpack too long. So I plan to remove it -- while still keeping it inside the backpack just at an angle -- to compress the backpack down to acceptable dimensions. But that's separate from the TSA / EU security scan. My concern is getting it past security, not onto the airplane.

Comment: It is a related issue though.  A metal stick (which this approximates given what passes for logic in security land) carried loose in a backpack is rather different to an integral part of the bag, even one that can be taken out.  My backpacks with metal frames are both far too long for the cabin so I've never tried it

Comment: I've flown many times in the US and EU with a similar wire-framed backpack and had no issues, though I left the frame installed (my pack is a bit smaller than yours I guess).

Comment: I plan to take it out of its holder after security and reconfigure it in the backpack (horizontally but still inside the backpack) before boarding the connecting flight in Europe, where length must be < 55cm. The US to EU flight just requires a total L + W + H under 114cm. It's a bit too twisted too be a stick, while also too long to be considered a coat hanger.

Comment: @zadrozny I wouldn't take it out. They're much *more* likely to think it's some kind of weapon, if it's not installed in the bag. If it's in the bag and they ask what it is, you say it's part of the bag. Don't try to pretend it's a coat hanger... just say it's a part of the bag, because that's the truth. If they ask.